# Equivalent integral equation to initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to prove that any continuous solutions of integral equation  $$y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(t,y(t))\, dt$$ is a solution of the ivp $$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)),\;y(x_0)=y_0?$$

Comment: You need to edit this question.  Are you aiming for something like $x(t) = x_0+\int_{t_0}^t d\tau \, f(x(\tau))$?

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $y(x)$ must be continuously differentiable.

Take the derivative of the integral equation using the fundamental theorem of calculus.